# Automatic Content Negotation When Assigning To Response

Tags: c#, nancy

How can I take advantage of the content negotiation pipeline when assigning to `NancyContext.Response`?

Currently my  `IStatusCodeHandler.Handle` method returns JSON regardless of any content negotiation.

I want this method to use JSON or XML according on any  content negotiation (preferably using the content negotiation pipeline.)

```
public void Handle(HttpStatusCode statusCode, NancyContext context)
{
    var error = new { StatusCode = statusCode, Message = "Not Found" };
    context.Response =
        new JsonResponse(error, new JsonNetSerializer())
            .WithStatusCode(statusCode);
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In the default Nancy engine, the status code handlers are invoked after content negotiation has already taken place. If you're using version 0.23 or newer, the content negotiation parts have been pulled out into a separate service and can be used anywhere, at any time, just given a model and the context. Using this service, the [`IResponseNegotiator`](https://github.com/NancyFx/Nancy/pull/1348), you should be able to renegotiate using the error model.

Something like this:

```
public class MyStatusCodeHandler : IStatusCodeHandler
{
    private readonly IResponseNegotiator _negotiator;

    public MyStatusCodeHandler(IResponseNegotiator negotiator)
    {
        _negotiator = negotiator;
    }

    public bool HandlesStatusCode(HttpStatusCode statusCode, NancyContext context)
    {
        return statusCode == HttpStatusCode.NotFound;
    }

    public void Handle(HttpStatusCode statusCode, NancyContext context)
    {
        var error = new { StatusCode = statusCode, Message = "Not Found" };
        context.Response = _negotiator.NegotiateResponse(error, context);
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the response. This code, however, throws a `NullReferenceException`. I took a picture of the stack trace for you http://i.imgur.com/36OLtqG.png .

Comment: No exception is thrown when I pass a string though o.o http://i.imgur.com/xoNisVs.png

Comment: Could be a bug, and that's something for the Nancy issue tracker, not SO. Anyway, that's the way to do it, and the way Nancy does content negotiation internally.

Comment: You mean to say that there is no other way to use content negotiation pipeline in this manner until this bug is fixed? I will submit an Issue on GH shortly.

Comment: The bug is because the `NancyContext` doesn't have a `NegotiationContext` set. This is because it's set in the `DefaultNancyModuleBuilder` and that's not hit when you have a 404. It should work for other status codes and in other places. I've submitted a failing test [here](https://github.com/NancyFx/Nancy/pull/1560). In the mean time, you can just set `context.NegotiationContext = new NegotiationContext()` before passing it to the negotiator :)